# Measure of Arbitrary Union of Null Set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $N$ be a null set. Suppose that for each $x\in N$ we have a null set $N_x$. Can we conclude that $\bigcup_{x\in N}N_x$ is a null set? (I know that the uncountable union of null set could be non-measurable, but here we are talking about a little more specific case where the possible uncountable union is taken over the null set)

If it is not true that $\bigcup_{x\in N}N_x$ is necessarily measurable, then does knowing $\bigcup_{x\in N}N_x$ is measurable allow us to conclude that it is a null set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, we cannot conclude this.  A null set can be uncountable, and indeed in bijection with $\mathbb R$  (consider the Cantor set).  Therefore if $b\colon N\to \mathbb R$ is such a bijection, we may define $N$ as the Cantor set and $N_x=\{b(x)\}$, and we have $\bigcup_{x\in N}N_x =\mathbb R$.

#### Remark

Note that if we just ask for a surjection onto $\mathbb R$, which already gives the same counterexample, then we can even have $b$ be continuous, so this is not a particularly pathological construction.

Comment: Hah, beat me to it by seconds!